# How to make textarea fit the text content onKeyUp event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have a `textarea`

```
<textarea>
Very long content. Very long content. Very long content. 
Very long content. Very long content. Very long content. 
Very long content. Very long content. Very long content. 
Very long content. Very long content. Very long content. 
Very long content. Very long content. Very long content. 
Very long content. Very long content. Very long content. 
</textarea>
```

and I want to make the `textarea` fit the text in the textarea as the user type in it with the code below

```
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  textarea.style.height = `${textarea.scrollHeight}px`;
})
```

It works fine when the user add more text to the textarea. The problem is when the user clear the text inside and start typing again, the **text area will not shrink to fit the text**.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your textarea will only assume the height of the content at its maximum height. You need to set its height to `0px` before getting its `scrollHeight`

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should shrink the textarea when value is empty:

```
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  textarea.style.height = textarea.value.length ? `${textarea.scrollHeight}px` : 'auto';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With this method, you can achieve what you want.

```
function calcHeight(value) {
  let numberOfLineBreaks = (value.match(/\n/g) || []).length;
  // min-height + lines x line-height + padding + border
  let newHeight = 20 + numberOfLineBreaks * 20 + 12 + 2;
  return newHeight;
}

let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
textarea.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  textarea.style.height = calcHeight(textarea.value) + "px";
});
```

You can also use `span` to create a `textarea` that has the result you want.

HTML:

```
<span class="textarea"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```